# Can I bound this somehow?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we are given $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(b_k)$ where $\sum_{k=1}^n(b_k)$ gives the sum of the $1$s in the binary representation of some dyadic $x$, and we suppose that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, does this imply that the sequence $F_n$ where $F_n =\sum_{k=1}^n(1-2b_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1^{b_k})$ is bounded by some constant?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: Of course it is not necessarily bounded. A counterexample is trivial to construct.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the counterexample
$$x = 0.10110101101010101...$$
the concatenation of $2^k + 1$ ones alternating with $2^k$ zeros for all whole k.

For a length C, there are less than $\log_2{C}$ more ones than zeros, and the density is bounded by $0.5 + \frac{\log_2{C}}{C}$, which goes to $0.5$.

But the difference is not bounded.

Comment: See, normally we don't answer questions until the OP as much as shows that they are capable of comprehending the answer. Besides, your counterexample is wrong, $f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @IvanNeretin If I'm understanding the issue correctly, it would be a correct counterexample if it alternated between 1 and 0 instead, right (101, 10101, 101010101)?

Comment: With regard to the issue of homework/other low effort posters, I think that answering the question can be valuable for other people, and that moderators can handle that issue if it recurs by punishing the asker. Though I am going to look on the meta forum to see if there is any discussion on this.

Comment: If it alternated between 1 and 0, then the difference would be bounded.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. Each digit group is alternating (101, 10101, 101010101), but each digit groups has more 1 than 0, and the final x is the their concatenation. I have edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: Yes, this will do.